# javascript regex pattern with a variable string not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a function that will pass some parameters to a regex script:

```
function classAttributes( classString, className ) {
    var data;
    var regex = new RegExp(className+"\[(.*?)\]");
    var matches = classString.match(regex);

    if ( matches ) {
        //matches[1] refers to options inside [] "required, email, ..."
            var spec = matches[1].split(/,\s*/);

            if ( spec.length > 0 ) {
                data = spec;
            }
    }

    return data;
}
```

but for some reason it doesnt like the string variable that I pass it "new RegExp(className+"[(.*?)]");"
it doesnt throw an error but the validation doesnt work.

Edit:
I will take the information from the class stribute and pass it as classString

```
<div class="field-character-count test[asd, 123, hello]"></div>
```

and the "className" will represent "test"

Comment: what exactly do classString and className contain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to escape the backslashes inside the search string  -

```
var regex = new RegExp(className+"\\[(.*?)\\]");
```